# How Do You Zoom In/Out Using Chromes Zoom

Tags: python, selenium

Couldn't find any answers other than one that didn't actually zoom out the same way, because when i tried grabbing elements they just came out as ' ' when it was too far zoomed out (Which Doesn't Happen With Manual Zoom) the code I tried then is:

> driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='25%'")

The reason I need this is there are elements a need to access that can only be seen by scrolling, but by zooming out it shows all of them. If there's another way to do that then that'll be fine

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to zoom out all the way. You can just scroll to the element using javascript.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: yeah, but its a list of answers and the sizes of the list can vary up to hundreds of elements, plus I need to get all elements in the list, if this can still be used then yay, in the meantime ill try experimenting with it

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, basically when I was looping through all elements with the classname of the things in the list, I did the command you suggested and it scrolled down a bit each one, showing more of them, then those scroll it down, etc till it reaches the bottom, thanks, stumped me for a while